# C++11 template function specialization with SFINAE allowing further specializations (error: call of overloaded function is ambiguous)

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish (please see comments) and what I have so far.
This code is compilable and runnable - [ideone link](http://ideone.com/VCf54u).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class ObjectMustBeCreatedType : public std::false_type {
  // needed for proper static_assert<T> below
};

// default function that has to be specialized, otherwise compiler error
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(const std::string &path) {
    static_assert(ObjectMustBeCreatedType<T>::value, 
                  "please specialize this for your class");
}

// SFINAE to detect static T::Create function
template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            std::shared_ptr<T>,
            decltype(T::Create(std::string{}))
        >::value
    >::type
>
std::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(const std::string &s) {
    return T::Create(s); // if T::Create is found, call it
}

// for this class the SFINAE version should be triggered 
// and CreateObject<AutomaticClass> should be instantiated automatically
struct AutomaticClass {
    static std::shared_ptr<AutomaticClass> Create(const std::string &s) {
        std::cout << "AutomaticClass::Create" << std::endl;
        return std::make_shared<AutomaticClass>();
    }
};

// for this class CreateObject is manually specialized below
struct ManualClass {
    ManualClass(const std::string &s) { 
      std::cout << "ManualClass constructor: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

// manual CreateObject<ManualClass> specialization
template<>
std::shared_ptr<ManualClass> CreateObject(const std::string &s) {
    std::cout << "CreateObject<ManualClass>" << std::endl;
    return std::make_shared<ManualClass>(s);
}

int main() {
    // this works
    CreateObject<ManualClass>("ManualClass test");

    // produces compile errors
    CreateObject<AutomaticClass>("AutomaticClass test");

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is that for SFINAE-valid case there now are two functions both matching the template, thus producing following errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:59:59: error: call of overloaded ‘CreateObject(const char [20])’ is ambiguous
         CreateObject<AutomaticClass>("AutomaticClass test");
                                                           ^
prog.cpp:12:24: note: candidate: std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> CreateObject(const string&) [with T = AutomaticClass; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
     std::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(const std::string &path) {
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:27:24: note: candidate: std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> CreateObject(const string&) [with T = AutomaticClass; <template-parameter-1-2> = void; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
     std::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(const std::string &s) {
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can this be fixed in such a way, that:

1. `CreateObject<T>` remains the same so further specialization for
   user classes looks as clean as possible.
2. Therefore, `CreateObject<T>` must not be moved to class to allow partial template specialization which is easier to do but would look
   dirty.
3. Default `static_assert` error message is kept so user clearly sees that he needs to specialize `CreateObject<T>` for his class.
4. Uses C++11 standard and not a higher one.

Comment: Your default case with the static assert is doing no blocking to ensure a ````Create```` call actually exists. Just put the negation of your automatic template (i.e. ````!std::is_same````) to guard and this should work fine.

Comment: @mascoj I tried that before - unfortunately, it brings a template redefinition error. Also, what if I want to specify multiple SFINAE-based automatic rules for various classes? Then the default function check would be really huge.

Comment: Hmmm, SFINAE always turns my head around. I'll think on it and let you know when I come up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that you need to switch from one function template to another one, and not just enable/disable one of two. In the latter you confuse the compiler with an ambiguity. I think, old good [member detector](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector) should do the job.

```
template <typename T>
struct has_static_member_create {
  template <typename U, std::shared_ptr<U> (*)(std::string const&)>
  struct Check;

  template <typename U>
  static std::true_type foo(Check<U, &U::Create>*);

  template <typename U>
  static std::false_type foo(...);

  constexpr static bool value = decltype(foo<T>(0))::value;
};

// More C++-11 style
// template <typename T, typename Enabled = void>
// struct has_static_member_create : std::false_type {};

// template <typename T>
// struct has_static_member_create<T,
//                                 typename std::
//                                   enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(&T::Create),
//                                                          std::shared_ptr<T> (*)(
//                                                            std::string const&)>::value>::
//                                     type> : std::true_type {};


// default function that has to be specialized, otherwise compiler error
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!has_static_member_create<T>::value, std::shared_ptr<T>>::type
CreateObject(const std::string& path) {
  static_assert(ObjectMustBeCreatedType<T>::value,
                "please specialize this for your class");
}

// SFINAE to detect static T::Create function
template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<has_static_member_create<T>::value>::type>
std::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(const std::string& s) {
  return T::Create(s); // if T::Create is found, call it
}

// for this class the SFINAE version should be triggered
// and CreateObject<AutomaticClass> should be instantiated automatically
struct AutomaticClass {
  static std::shared_ptr<AutomaticClass> Create(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << "AutomaticClass::Create" << std::endl;
    return std::make_shared<AutomaticClass>();
  }
};

// for this class CreateObject is manually specialized below
struct ManualClass {
  ManualClass(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << "ManualClass constructor: " << s << std::endl;
  }
};

// manual CreateObject<ManualClass> specialization
template <>
std::shared_ptr<ManualClass> CreateObject<ManualClass>(const std::string& s) {
  std::cout << "CreateObject<ManualClass>" << std::endl;
  return std::make_shared<ManualClass>(s);
}

int main() {
  // this works
  CreateObject<ManualClass>("ManualClass test");

  // produces compile errors
  CreateObject<AutomaticClass>("AutomaticClass test");

  cerr << has_static_member_create<AutomaticClass>::value << endl;
  cerr << has_static_member_create<ManualClass>::value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Feel free to play with other implementations of the detector and/or different function template enabling/disabling techniques. What I showed is just one of possibilities that works.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, this has a downside that adding more automatic specializations becomes quite messy, but this does solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use tag dispatching and stop it with all the specilization nonsense.

`Create<T>(s)` does `return Create( tag<T>, s )`.  Now we write the automatic one:

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> CreateObject(tag_t<T>, const std::string &s) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<T>,decltype(T::Create(std::string{}))>::value,
    "Please provide T::Create(string) or override `Create(tag_t<T>, string)` for your type"
  );
  return T::Create(s); // if T::Create is found, call it
}
```

You can improve the static assert with the detected idiom for cleaner errors when `::Create` does not exist.

Now instead of specializing `CreateObject` you just override it:

```
std::shared_ptr<ManualClass> CreateObject(tag_t<ManualClass>, const std::string& s) {
  std::cout << "CreateObject<ManualClass>" << std::endl;
  return std::make_shared<ManualClass>(s);
}
```

And best of all, this override can live in the namespace of `ManualClass` *or* `tag_t`.

Comment: I like the version without tag dispatching better so I accept another answer, but thank you, this also works!